# Randomly reduce the number of pages

Tags: luatex, fun

My colleagues and I wrote a book that has m pages. Our editor wants n << m pages. For fun, I'd like to submit him two versions of our book.

1. One version that randomly suppress (m - n) pages from the final output (I'd like to do it on-the-fly, that is discard a page once it has been shiped out).
2. One version that randomly suppress a fraction of characters so that the document has approximatively n pages.

I thought that the [`chickenize` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/chickenize) could help but, for once, it does not provide such useful functions.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Why not remove some chapters? If you remove pages randomly you'll broke the readability.

Comment: @Sigur We do want to break the readability `:)`.

Comment: You could put the entire page into a savebox, but you would need to hook into the end-of-page processing both before and after (somehow).

Comment: @JohnKormylo You made me think of `atbegshi` package. It has a `\AtBeginShipoutDiscard` that may help if I understand correctly its documentation.

Comment: For your #2: it might be easier to randomly suppress words than characters without destroying TeX compilability. I'd use a script in (python/perl/awk).

Comment: @EthanBolker For fun, I'd like to do it with `(lua)tex`. I have in mind luatex's `pre_linebreak_filter`. `post_line_break_filter` can suppress characters but it is too late (I think) to save space.

Comment: What about creating a "to-be-delivered.tex" in which you define a list of n random numbers from 1 to m and include the corresponded pages of "originalbook.tex" via `pdfpages`?

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino Yes. That's a solution for #1. But I'd like to see if we can do that on-the-fly. Speaking of `luatex`, there is a `pre_output` callback. Maybe it can help.

Comment: 1) If you remove pages at random you’re going to get dangling references in indices and lists.
2) I’d start with the ``pre_output_filter`` callback since that should give you access to the completed page.

Answer (score 6):

> Partially solved

This problem (part 1 of the question) was simply tempting, so I couldn't resist it even if my solution doesn't provide shipping out hackery. As I am improving my skills in LuaTeX, that beast, excuse me my keyboard mistyped that word, that beauty I meant, this task was a challenge.

Briefly said the LuaTeX code does:

1. It generates a simulated book 200 pages long (`mybook.{tex|pdf}`).
2. Using pseudorandom numbers it (`dump-me.tex`) dumps pages from a Lua table (a variable) containing all the pages at the beginning of the process. We cannot use pseudorandom numbers from an interval one to number of remaining pages directly, because some specific number could repeat itself, e.g. a row of 55, 32, 64, 89, and again 55. I dumped 56 pages, it can be specified on line 8 where we enter number of wanted pages.
3. It generates four TeX files and processes them to get PDFs into your working directory (`1-shuffled, 1-unshuffled, 2-sorted, 2-unsorted`). One version is a new book (un)sorted, the second version is a (un)sorted version of the dumped pages.
4. It leaves that mess in files in the working directory untouched (no removing or cleaning of anything at all). I rather write it in advance as the code uses command shell in the background. It is considered risky, generally speaking.
5. Then, I post-processed one of the files for purpose of this post manually (`completion.tex`).

I enclose the code:

```
%! lualatex --shell-escape dump-me.tex
%  or
%! lualatex --enable-write18 dump-me.tex
%  used in IDEs or use the command shell instead.

% I wish to have a book of 144 pages,
% therefore dump 56 of 200 pages in the example.
\def\wishtohavepages{144}

\def\mybook{mybook.pdf}
% "\\noexpand\\mybook" is a usual way
\directlua{mybookname="\mybook"} 

% These days we typeset+indent our work in editor and 
% program+store log information in document... ;-)
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\parindent=0pt

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybook.tex}
%! {pdf|xe|lua}latex mybook.tex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\font\myfont=cmr10 at 200pt \myfont
\newcount\mytemp \mytemp=0
\loop\newpage
\mbox{}\vfil\hfil\thepage
\advance\mytemp by 1
\ifnum\mytemp<200\repeat
\end{document}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
% First and last regular TeX line...
% Bye-bye TeX, welcome LuaTeX...
\textbf{Summary (log file)}

% Getting PDF from mybook.tex...
\begin{luacode*}
print("") print("") -- rather then backslash n backslash n
print("Processing mybook.tex...")
os.execute("lualatex --interaction=batchmode mybook.tex")
\end{luacode*}
% Load the PDF back to get number of pages...
\pdfximage{\mybook} 

\begin{luacode*}
-- Additional help function
function parit()
tex.print("\\par\\medskip")
end -- of parit function

-- Print results
function printme(s,exportto)
s=table.concat(s,",") -- to string with commas
toprocess="\\documentclass{article}\
\\usepackage{pdfpages}\
\\begin{document}\
\\includepdf[pages={"..s.."},fitpaper]{"..mybookname.."}\
\\end{document}"

-- Preparing the TeX file...
-- print(toprocess)
whereto=io.open(exportto,"w")
whereto:write(toprocess)
whereto:close()

-- Run the beast!... ;-)
print("") -- rather then \n, untested across operating systems
print("Processing "..exportto.."...")
os.execute("lualatex --interaction=batchmode "..exportto)
end -- of printme function

-- http://lua-users.org/wiki/CopyTable
-- Is there an easier way of copying tables? But this works...
-- Malipivo doesn't know on March 21, 2014.
function deepcopy(orig)
    local orig_type = type(orig)
    local copy
    if orig_type == 'table' then
        copy = {}
        for orig_key, orig_value in next, orig, nil do
            copy[deepcopy(orig_key)] = deepcopy(orig_value)
        end
        setmetatable(copy, deepcopy(getmetatable(orig)))
    else -- number, string, boolean, etc
        copy = orig
    end
    return copy
end

-- The core function
function randomizer(pages,wishtohave)

dump=pages-wishtohave
-- a simple verification of dump value
if dump>pages then dump=pages end
math.randomseed(1) -- to have repeateable results

local fulltable={}
for number=1,pages do
  fulltable[number]=number
end -- of for cycle

local sorted={} -- dumped pages
local unsorted={} -- dumped pages
local shuffled={} -- the rest of the pages (requested file)
local unshuffled={} -- the rest of the pages (requested file)
local shorttable=fulltable -- a temporary table, items are being removed 

for number=1, pages do
dumping=math.random(1,pages-number+1) -- nth value to dump
if number<=dump then
  table.insert(sorted,shorttable[dumping])
else
  table.insert(shuffled,shorttable[dumping])
end
table.remove(shorttable,dumping)  
end -- of for
parit()

tex.print("Shuffled remaining pages\\par")
tex.print(shuffled)
parit()

tex.print("Unshuffled remaining pages\\par")
unshuffled=deepcopy(shuffled)
table.sort(unshuffled)
tex.print(unshuffled)
parit()

tex.print("Unsorted dumped pages\\par")
unsorted=deepcopy(sorted)
tex.print(unsorted)
parit()

tex.print("Sorted dumped pages\\par")
table.sort(sorted)
tex.print(sorted)
parit()

-- Enough talking to TeX, now, prepare the real PDF files...
--print("") -- Escape middle of the line in command shell...
printme(shuffled,"1-shuffled.tex")
printme(unshuffled,"1-unshuffled.tex")
printme(unsorted,"2-unsorted.tex")
printme(sorted,"2-sorted.tex")

-- A return to the real world...
end -- of function randomizer
\end{luacode*}

% Real typesetting...
% The beast and its beauty... :-)
\directlua{randomizer(\the\pdflastximagepages,\wishtohavepages)}

% Some starting point references...
% http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Programming_in_LuaTeX
% http://wiki.luatex.org/index.php/Writing_Lua_in_TeX
\end{document}
```

We process the main code either by:

> lualatex --shell-escape dump-me.tex

or by

> lualatex --enable-write18 dump-me.tex

It relies on your TeX distribution. If everything is running successfully you should see these five lines on the terminal somewhere.

> Processing mybook.tex...
>
> Processing 1-shuffled.tex...
>
> Processing 1-unshuffled.tex...
>
> Processing 2-unsorted.tex...
>
> Processing 2-sorted.tex...

The main file generates and processes these files on-the-fly, this is the content of the first one, `1-shuffled.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages={58,168,7,75,19,137,12,5,184,57,56,120,140,167,145,97,43,150,94,89,190,147,23,117,78,146,122,111,68,31,46,85,161,103,196,152,66,33,132,98,14,142,100,27,189,28,182,138,62,83,15,193,134,32,176,166,114,41,40,162,88,26,102,151,80,55,115,135,155,144,87,20,69,175,8,104,131,81,17,191,185,108,64,86,67,172,54,84,50,197,52,154,116,36,158,177,73,99,181,6,195,112,10,106,38,169,128,130,42,171,21,16,143,60,188,51,65,22,153,159,129,109,139,47,11,2,25,178,183,63,45,123,9,71,95,157,133,93,48,124,76,194,82,186},fitpaper]{mybook.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Finally, you should see one resulting page, I enclose a preview of that page.

[image: preview 1]

If you check your working directory there are 4 new PDF files. We may post-process one, some or all of them in TeX. I picked up one PDF file manually.

```
%! lualatex completion.tex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages={-},nup=12x12,frame]{1-shuffled.pdf}
\end{document}
```

This is probably the file you would like to hand over to the editor. One plain page with almost complete book with pages shuffled... :-)

[image: preview 2]

Comment: @cjorssen Anytime, I'm glad I could help!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a latex approach to question #1 using the `atbegshi` package together with `tikz` to generate the random pages (I tried using `lcg` first, but it seems to seed its random generator using the time that the file was saved with the result that the random pages were not so random unless you saved the file...). It's not quite as comprehensive as Malipivo's answer

You can set the number of pages to be printed in the preamble with `\NumberOfPagesToPrint`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcount\NumberOfPagesToPrint     % total number of pages to print
\NumberOfPagesToPrint=8

\makeatletter
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{atbegshi}

% total number of pages in (main) document
\AtEndDocument{\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\newlabel{TotalNumberOfPages}{{0}{\thepage}}}}

\newcount\@PagesStillToPrint
\newcount\@TotalPages
\AtBeginDocument{
  \ifdefined\r@TotalNumberOfPages
    \@TotalPages=\number\pageref{TotalNumberOfPages}
  \else
    \@TotalPages=\NumberOfPagesToPrint
  \fi
  \@PagesStillToPrint=\@TotalPages
  \advance\@PagesStillToPrint -\NumberOfPagesToPrint
}
\newif\if@notShipping

\AtBeginShipout{
    % randomly decide to ship this page UNLESS we need to print all
    % of the remaining pages in order to fulfil our page quota
    \ifnum\@PagesStillToPrint>\@TotalPages
      % already printed enough pages
      \AtBeginShipoutDiscard%
    \else
      \ifnum\c@page>\@PagesStillToPrint % need all remaining pages
        \@notShippingfalse
      \else % randomly decide whether to print this page
         \pgfmathrandominteger{\@shippingProb}{0}{1}
         \ifnum\@shippingProb=1
            \@notShippingfalse
         \else
            \@notShippingtrue
         \fi
       \fi
       \if@notShipping
         \AtBeginShipoutDiscard%
       \else
         \global\advance\@PagesStillToPrint by 1  % =total pages - pages left
       \fi
     \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Page 1\newpage
Page 2\newpage
Page 3\newpage
Page 4\newpage
Page 5\newpage
Page 6\newpage
Page 7\newpage
Page 8\newpage
Page 9\newpage
Page 10\newpage
Page 11\newpage
Page 12\newpage
Page 13\newpage
Page 14\newpage
Page 15\newpage
Page 16\newpage
Page 17\newpage

\end{document}
```