# Generating practice sheets for characters

Tags: tables, random-numbers

I'm currently learning japanese, and since they have different characters, I'm doing some practice where I make a table, in which each cell contains the pronounciation of one of their characters, and an empty box below that I can type the character in after printing the sheet.

[image: a box]

The problem is that I would like to have the order of the characters be different each time, so I'm looking for a way, such that I can create a LaTeX document which when compiled gives a page filled like the above image, with each A being some item in a given list.

It's fine if the randomness is supplied from somewhere else if LaTeX cannot create randomness itself, such as a seperate document that I simply put the time in, or a commandline parameter.

If it makes the process any easier I have created the following template which I would like the documents to follow. My question would be answered if the `\nextchar` macro is replaced with something that picked a random character from some set of given characters.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{easytable}

\newcommand{\nextchar}{{\Huge A}}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\begin{center}
  \begin{TAB}(e,12ex,5ex){|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \nextchar & \nextchar & \nextchar & \nextchar & \nextchar & \nextchar & \nextchar & \nextchar & \nextchar & \nextchar \\
              &&&&&&&&&\\
    \nextchar & \nextchar & \nextchar & \nextchar & \nextchar & \nextchar & \nextchar & \nextchar & \nextchar & \nextchar \\
              &&&&&&&&&\\
    \nextchar & \nextchar & \nextchar & \nextchar & \nextchar & \nextchar & \nextchar & \nextchar & \nextchar & \nextchar \\
              &&&&&&&&&\\
    \nextchar & \nextchar & \nextchar & \nextchar & \nextchar & \nextchar & \nextchar & \nextchar & \nextchar & \nextchar \\
              &&&&&&&&&\\
    \nextchar & \nextchar & \nextchar & \nextchar & \nextchar & \nextchar & \nextchar & \nextchar & \nextchar & \nextchar \\
              &&&&&&&&&\\
    \nextchar & \nextchar & \nextchar & \nextchar & \nextchar & \nextchar & \nextchar & \nextchar & \nextchar & \nextchar \\
              &&&&&&&&&\\
    \nextchar & \nextchar & \nextchar & \nextchar & \nextchar & \nextchar & \nextchar & \nextchar & \nextchar & \nextchar \\
              &&&&&&&&&\\
  \end{TAB}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you please provide MWE, or do you have a PDF file with information about one character per page, or you have some data?

Comment: @Malipivo Please elaborate on ''MWE'', what do you mean with ''PDF file with information about one character per page'', and what kind of information do you want?

Comment: MWE (http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) is a code we can start working on it. Sometimes it is useful to have cards (e.g. one kanji per page) and then a task is to select some of them from huge pdf using pgfpages/tikz or similar tools.
We would like to help you, but your question is too general.

Comment: @Malipivo That's a reasonable request, how would the best method be for me to provide the document the characters to put in the boxes? A pdf with one on each page as you mentioned? Some kind of array containing the LaTeX code for whatever to put in the box?

Comment: TikZ can handle randomness nicely, see `rnd` and `rand` functions in the reference manual. A tip for you, how we can select some pages out of a big PDF file in LuaTeX (selecting pages without repetitions), http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145160/randomly-reduce-the-number-of-pages/166865#166865.

Comment: @Malipivo I added a MWE. About LuaTeX, I would prefer if it could be done from tex live, however I can install LuaTeX if it's necessary.

Comment: LuaTeX is already installed with TeX Live -- it's just another engine, like `pdftex` or `xetex`.

Comment: @SeanAllred Oh yeah, I can see that, in that case a solution using LuaTeX is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a LuaLaTeX-based solution. You have to store your characters into `charlist` (the variable) as shown below. Then it will count the list and uses randomly chosen characters using your `\nextchar` macro.

[image: random table]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{easytable}

\directlua{
    charlist = {"A","B","C","D","E","F","G"}
    maxv = 0
    for _ in pairs(charlist) do maxv = maxv + 1 end
}
\newcommand{\nextchar}{{\Huge%
    \directlua{
        tex.print(charlist[math.random(1,maxv)])
    }
}}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\begin{center}
  \begin{TAB}(e,12ex,5ex){|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \nextchar & \nextchar & \nextchar & \nextchar & \nextchar & \nextchar & \nextchar & \nextchar & \nextchar & \nextchar \\
              &&&&&&&&&\\
    \nextchar & \nextchar & \nextchar & \nextchar & \nextchar & \nextchar & \nextchar & \nextchar & \nextchar & \nextchar \\
              &&&&&&&&&\\
    \nextchar & \nextchar & \nextchar & \nextchar & \nextchar & \nextchar & \nextchar & \nextchar & \nextchar & \nextchar \\
              &&&&&&&&&\\
    \nextchar & \nextchar & \nextchar & \nextchar & \nextchar & \nextchar & \nextchar & \nextchar & \nextchar & \nextchar \\
              &&&&&&&&&\\
    \nextchar & \nextchar & \nextchar & \nextchar & \nextchar & \nextchar & \nextchar & \nextchar & \nextchar & \nextchar \\
              &&&&&&&&&\\
    \nextchar & \nextchar & \nextchar & \nextchar & \nextchar & \nextchar & \nextchar & \nextchar & \nextchar & \nextchar \\
              &&&&&&&&&\\
    \nextchar & \nextchar & \nextchar & \nextchar & \nextchar & \nextchar & \nextchar & \nextchar & \nextchar & \nextchar \\
              &&&&&&&&&\\
  \end{TAB}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```